# Where does Context.Track<T> information go?

Tags: workflow-activity

I have tried

```
public sealed class WriteMessage : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.Track(new BuildInformationRecord<Foo>()
        {
            Value = FooInstance,
        });
    }
}
```

and

then found an overload on `context.Track` that accepts `<T>`

`context.Track(FooInstance);`

and neither one appears in the build viewer in visual studio.

`context.TrackBuildMessage(string data)` certainly does.

and I'm not getting any exception, is it being saved to the tfs data store, or a file? or is just silently failing entirely?

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/11/17/tfs-2010-customizing-build-information.aspx) to one of the resources implicating how this works or should work from the code side

Answer (score 1):

it actually does make it its way to the datastore. Your instance is converted into a Dictionnary<String,String> by reflection on its properties (you may provide a type converter to Dictionnary<String,String> if you like) then stored as a build record into the database. Records are logically structured as a tree. You may retrieve this info through the TFS API.

You are using a new type for TFS which is "Foo". Thus, your info cannot *yet* be displayed on the build reports in Visual Studio because VS doesn't know how to represent it. You actually need to extend VS build reports with a custom addin that can convert this into WPF controls for rendering.

If you track a "BuildMessage", this is a well known type by VS, it will be displayed in the build log.

You may as well develop a Warehouse adapter to bring this data from the stored build reports to the TFS warehouse store (and also the TFS cube).

About adding custom info into the build :

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/11/19/tfs-2010-customizing-build-information-part-2.aspx (and have a look at part 1)

My article on my blog in french (answers exactly your question, sorry, yeah... french) :

- http://blogs.codes-sources.com/vlabz/archive/2011/09/24/tfs-2010-enrichir-les-donn-es-d-un-build.aspx

Hope this helps.
(I can't post more links at the moment since I'm a new user, contact me directly I'll send you nice URLs, or google for "Changing The Way Build Information IS Displayed")